# PHP errors in browser not showing (using Docker)

Tags: php, docker

I am a beginner in PHP and have a problem. My browser is not showing the errors from a PHP file. It only says This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500. I want the errors to be displayed(like a notice). I am using Docker. I have searched everywhere and don't know what to do. Please help.

p.s Also I can not find my php.ini file. Tried putting this code in the PHP file , but still it doesn't work

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
```

Comment: `ini_set("display_errors", true)` instead of `ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL)`. Also using `phpinfo()` you can get your whole config with a list of all ini files used.

Comment: Still doesn't work :(

Comment: Whats the exact error?

Comment: Just to check - you're using PHP in a docker container?

Comment: @Grumpy this is my exact error  This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: @Jay yes, I am using PHP in a docker container

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to the question.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Comment: No i haven't ,even though I have put the error code lines in the PHP document

Comment: Check your error.log for the exact error.